# How to setup iOS MDM server?

Tags: ios, server, enterprise, mdm

My app has been released previously.
This time, won the enterprise account for MDM solutions applied.
And MDM certificate was received.

I already have an Ubuntu Server, I try to apply it MDM server.

For help if you have a document for the process of building the MDM server. T_T

This service is up to 10,000 people uses, I am not thinking os x server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try WSO2 EMM. http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/

If you want to build your own MDM, this may help you. https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server

(I didn't try it before)